# Is there any way to list the passed and failed releases in Azuredevops for a specific period of time

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

Looking for a way to visualise the statistics of seperate releasepipelines with history like, for the last 2 weeks or, 4weeks time, how many of the release pipelines passed and howmany failed ( if failed the error message)

Checking whether ADO has the inbuilt or out of the box feature to eable this.